# Maven: How do I mark a jar as sealed?

Tags: maven

This sounds so simple, so why an I struggling?

Is there a POM entry I can use to seal all the packages?

Or do I provide a manifest with value 'Sealed: true'?

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Comment: Dou you mean to sign artifacts ? I don't know what "Sealed" means in manifest file?

Comment: @khmarbaise: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*> Or do I provide a manifest with value 'Sealed: true'?*

As explained in ["Manifest Customization"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Sealed>true</Sealed>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I don't think the `<index>` and `<manifest>` elements are strictly needed.

Comment: @seanf, I can verify that the `<index>` and `<manifest>` are unnecessary.  I tested by running `mvn package verify && unzip -c target/my-artifact-id-version.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.